# How do i change the text and icon of Woocommerce social icons in WordPress on the product archive pages?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

In my Woocommerce single product page, I have social share buttons that i would like to change the text, as well as each icon. For example, change the facebook from "share on facebook" to "share on fb", and change the icon to my own custom icon.

You can see the page here. [here](https://helenmilan.com/product/onyx-stainless-steel-straws-smoothie/) Below is a screenshot of the same page. There are icons in the footer, but i am only referring to the buttons above that, seen in screenshot.

1. I am assuming i need to edit some woo theme files which is fine, can anyone tell me which?
2. The icons use font awesome now - what woo theme files might i edit to set each to its own jpeg? (If i could do it with CSS, even better!)

I am using Avada theme.

[image]

Comment: This is related to your theme provided icons that is hooking on `woocommerce_share` action hook on woocommerce. So you should better search and ask in your theme's support pages. This should be related to settings in your theme normally.

Comment: You might find a better answer on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/. That's where the wordpress experts will be.

Comment: thank you - the theme's settings are wide but limited on this one specific feature. i have only found an on / off that references a master list of links settings. I will continue to look in the theme's support.

Comment: thanks Dan, that is what I needed!